# What do the colours of android reputation widgets mean?

Tags: support, android-app, android-app-widgets

Just out of interest, what are the different background colours of the reputation widgets intended to signify?

[image]

It's not a distinction between/of:

- graduated or not
- having an own domain or *.stackexchange.com
- amount of rep

Is it a design choice made for every site separately? In that case I find the choice of blue for SO and gray for AskUbuntu a bit odd, personally.